# In a script running via child_process.spawn(), how can I omit stdout data from dependencies and only include what I want?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, child-process, spawn

I am executing a script via `child_process.spawnSync()`, and returning data to the parent process via `process.stdout.write()` in the child. However, some of the dependencies of the child process (e.g. other node packages) are writing to `stdout` as well. Is there any way to suppress this so that only the data I intentionally write to `stdout` gets written?

Currently, I am simply surrounding my output with `__my_output__` and then splitting the resulting string on that in the parent process. It works, but I'm hoping there's something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I am using node version 10.14.2

One option is to use the stdio config option in `child_process.spawnSync`:
[child_process.spawnSync docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options)

I do not have experience using this config option yet.

(Second option) I have experimented using `children_process.fork`: [child_process.fork docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

`spawnSync` is synchronous while `fork` is asynchronous. You can
replicate the behavior of `spawnSync` with `fork` by using callback functions.

Brief description of fork:

> The child_process.fork() method is a special case of
>   child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js
>   processes. Like child_process.spawn(), a ChildProcess object is
>   returned. The returned ChildProcess will have an additional
>   communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back
>   and forth between the parent and child. See subprocess.send() for
>   details.

This allows the parent process and child process to communicate on a "Clean/Elegant Line".

Here is an example using 2 files:

First File: parent.js

```
// Filename: parent.js
const cp = require('child_process');
/* Use cp.fork to create a child process, passing in the child process
   file's path as an argument
*/
const n1 = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/child.js`);

n1.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Got message from child', msg);
  if (msg.op == 'getdata') {
    console.log('getdata returned:', msg.data);
    n1.send({ msg: 'exit' });
  }
});

// Call the send function of the child process to send it data.
// I am sending an object that has a string which represents a command.
n1.send({ msg: 'push 5' });
n1.send({ msg: 'push 7' });
n1.send({ msg: 'push 11' });
n1.send({ msg: 'push 13' });
n1.send({ msg: 'getdata' });


n1.on('exit', (code) => {

  /*
  Code that needs to be executed after the child process is finished.
  */

  process.exit(0);
});

process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log('Parent process exited with code: ' + code);
});
```

Second File: child.js

```
// Filename: child.js
var myData = [];

var parseData = function (msg) {
// This function parses the string sent to the child process by the parent
  if (msg && typeof (msg) == 'string') {
    let msgArr = msg.split(' ')
    if (msgArr.length == 2 && msgArr[0].toLowerCase() == 'push') {
      myData.push(msgArr[1]);
      process.send({ op: 'push', msg: `${msgArr[1]} added to myData` });
    }
    else if (msgArr.length == 1 && msgArr[0].toLowerCase() == 'getdata') {
      process.send({ op: 'getdata', msg: 'returning data', data: myData });
    }
    else if (msgArr.length == 1 && msgArr[0].toLowerCase() == 'exit') {
      process.exit(0);
    }
    else {
      process.send({ op: 'unknown', msg: 'Could not parse parent\'s msg...' });
    }

  }
}

process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Got message from parent', msg);
  parseData(msg.msg);
});

process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log('Child process exit with code: ' + code);
});
```

In a command line, I use git bash, run the command `node parent`

Here is the output:

```
Got message from parent { msg: 'push 5' }
Got message from parent { msg: 'push 7' }
Got message from parent { msg: 'push 11' }
Got message from parent { msg: 'push 13' }
Got message from parent { msg: 'getdata' }
Got message from child { op: 'push', msg: '5 added to myData' }
Got message from child { op: 'push', msg: '7 added to myData' }
Got message from child { op: 'push', msg: '11 added to myData' }
Got message from child { op: 'push', msg: '13 added to myData' }
Got message from child { op: 'getdata',
  msg: 'returning data',
  data: [ '5', '7', '11', '13' ] }
getdata returned: [ '5', '7', '11', '13' ]
Got message from parent { msg: 'exit' }
Child process exit with code: 0
Parent process exited with code: 0
```

Include code that needs to be run strictly after the child process's completion
in the callback of the child process's exit listener in the parent.js file.

If there are multiple child processes (n1, n2, n3, ...) then you could create an
array of promises and use the Promise.all function:

```
let p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  n1.on('exit', (code) => {
    if ( code == 0 /* Or some other success criteria */) {
        resolve(true);
    }
  }
});

// do the same for p2, p3 and so on. You may choose to use a loop.
// Then call Promise.all with an array of the promises as an argument.

Promise.all([
  p1,
  p2,
  p3,
  ...
]).then(function(values) {
  /*
  If code needs to be completed after all child process's have exited, then
  you can put it here.
  */
process.exit(0);
});
```